# async - await начало

Tags: python, асинхронность

Только начал знакомится с асинхронным программированием, и не понял как я на самом элементарном словил ошибку

```
async def hi():
    await print(1)
hi()
```

Ошибка -

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'hi' was never awaited
  hi()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: Мб лучше было сначала дочитать урок по асинхронному программированию? :) Думаю, вам нужно было так вызывать `await hi()`. Странно видеть, что у `print` `await`, или у вас там выше `print` переопределен на асинхронный?

Comment: `async def hi():
    print(1)
await hi()`
Этот код тоже не работает вылазит ошибка 
`SyntaxError: 'await' outside function`